# How to find matches faster with SpaCy Matcher?

Tags: machine-learning, text, nlp, data-science, spacy

I'm trying to use the [SpaCy Matcher package](https://spacy.io/api/matcher) to detect matches whenever there is a passive voice in the sentences. I've written the pattern below and it finds the passive verbs and sentences correctly. Though my problem right now is with speed. I have around 1 million records and each record has around 10 sentences. I was wondering whether I can do anything to make the search a bit more efficient? Like not returning the end and start tokens?

The matcher:

```
matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
passive_rule1 = [{'DEP':'nsubjpass', 'OP':'*'}, {'DEP':'xcomp', 'OP':'*'}, {'DEP':'aux','OP':'*'},{'DEP':'auxpass'}, {'DEP':'nsubj', 'OP':'*'}, {'TAG':'VBN'}]
passive_rule2 =  [{'DEP': 'attr'}, {'DEP':'det', 'OP':'*'}, {'Tag':'NOUN', 'OP': '?'}, {'TAG':'VBN'}]

matcher.add('passive_rule1',None, passive_rule1)
matcher.add('passive_rule2 ', None, passive_rule2)
```

Finding matches:

```
df.loc[:, 'PassiveVoice'] = df.Sentence.apply(lambda x:1 if len(matcher(nlp(x)))>0 else 0)
```

Or if there is any other thing anyone has in mind I'll be happy to hear!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting your 1 mln. texts into a pandas' `dataframe` and then calling `nlp` 1 mln times in a loop is a bad idea. Instead, put your documents in a list, via `df["Sentence"].tolist()`, and process them efficiently via [`nlp.pipe`](https://spacy.io/api/language#pipe):

```py
import spacy
from spacy.matcher import Matcher

nlp = spacy.load("en_core_web_md", disable=["ner"])

matcher = Matcher(nlp.vocab)
passive_rule1 = [
    {"DEP": "nsubjpass", "OP": "*"},
    {"DEP": "xcomp", "OP": "*"},
    {"DEP": "aux", "OP": "*"},
    {"DEP": "auxpass"},
    {"DEP": "nsubj", "OP": "*"},
    {"TAG": "VBN"},
]
passive_rule2 = [
    {"DEP": "attr"},
    {"DEP": "det", "OP": "*"},
    {"Tag": "NOUN", "OP": "?"},
    {"TAG": "VBN"},
]

matcher.add("passive_rule1", None, passive_rule1)
matcher.add("passive_rule2", None, passive_rule2)

texts = ["this is my first sentence. about something", "this is another"]
# texts = df["Sentence"].tolist()
docs = nlp.pipe(texts, n_process = 2, batch_size=50)

for doc in docs:
    if matcher(doc):
        #do something
```

In addition note, with `nlp.pipe()` you can turn multiprocessing on with `n_process=2` (choose yours) and batch process your texts with `batch_size=50` (choose yours).

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Although I have some issues here. I ran the code on my system and unfortunately got 1-minute runtime on the one example that I use to get 9 seconds on! Although when I ran the code on Colab, I could get around 2 seconds which is a great improvement. Can you tell why I couldn't do the same on my own system? I see that I have 12 cores whereas Colab offers 2.

Comment: When you compare runtime of the same code on 2 different machines it is CPU/GPU spec is what matters. CPU frequency, cache size, RAM type, anything. You may check if the code is identical.

Comment: This task is completely dependent on the CPU, isn't it? So they should perform similarly. I'm still looking to see why I can't get any better results, do you think I should have any prerequisites for this pipeline to run faster?(like spacy-nightly)

Comment: Thanks to @Sergey I could construct a good function for detecting passive voice. Although the problem with the speed turns out to be because of the overheads of changing cores, which will be insignificant when using large groups of records and datasets. [Here is my repository](https://github.com/mitramir55/Text-mining-in-marketing/blob/master/exp8.ipynb) if anyone still had questions on this.